# how to call the static method directly from the inherited java class?

Tags: scala

I have a **java class** `PApplet` to be inherited and it has some **static methods(fields)**(eg. `map`)

so I use the code like

```
trait SomeTrait extends PApplet 
 ...
object SomeObject extends SomeTrait 
 ...
```

I can not call `SomeObject.map` because the method doesn't belonged to `SomeTrait` or `SomeObject`.

```
object SomeObject extends PApplet
```

still no help because of the same reason.

```
object PApplet extends PApplet
```

It works,but It makes no meaning.I cannot extends a object.

There are some solutions though:

```
import PApplet._
```

or

```
trait SomeTrait extends PApplet {
  def map = PApplet.map _
}
```

The first one seems verbose that I should import every time I use the static method in my code.

The second one meets the same problem if there are too many static methods.

Is there some solution to just inherit the java class and use the static method directly? just like `SomeObject.map`

Answer (score 0):

Word static means it's specific to that class and not to Trait. You can't inherit it.

I think the best you can do is to import the static method's/fields as you have shown.